/a/ et /ɑ/ dans « travail » et « bataille »
Bonjour,
J'ai une question concernant la prononciation de [a] et [ɑ] dans travail [tʀavaj] et bataille [batɑ:j].
Aujourd'hui, la différence entre a antérieur [a] et a postérieur [ɑ], est peut-être moins consciente. Cependant, de nombreux dictionnaires semblent faire la distinction entre les deux prononciations (les prononciations des mots respectifs ci-dessus sont tirées du TLFi).
Ma question est la suivante : est-il possible de distinguer ces deux prononciations sur la base de l'orthographe ?
Par exemple, il est connu que le a avec accent circomflexe â est souvent prononcé comme [ɑ] (pâte [pɑ:t] / patte [pat]).
Mais comment distinguer les différentes prononciations de travail et bataille sur l'orthographe ? Comment ces différences de prononciation sont-elles apparues ?
Dans le cas de pâte, par exemple, le s de paste a cessé d’être prononcé, ce qui a entraîné un allongement compensatoire de la prononciation du a qui le précède. (Voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allongement_compensatoire : « Le /aː/ résultant de l'allongement compensatoire du /a/ a par la suite évolué en /ɑ/ en français moderne (noté ‹ â ›). »
Mais comment expliquer l’origine de la différence de prononciation entre travail et bataille ?
Je vous remercie par avance.

En ce qui me concerne, je ne perçois pas la différence phonétique sur la dernière syllabe de "bétail" et "bataille" ou entre "un travail" et "quelqu'un travaille". Mais, je ne suis pas vraiment une référence dans ce domaine, distinguant à peine le "é" et le "è".

Je prononce [bataj] et je ne dois pas être la seule. La plupart des dictionnaires que je viens de consulter donnent les deux (dont le TLFi : «  [batɑ:j]. Les dict. indiquent un l mouillé, jusqu'à Littré inclus (et avec l'exception de Land. 1834).Enq. : /bataj/. ») J'en ai trouvé un qui n'en donne qu'une (Robert bilingue) et c'est [bataj].  Travail c'est toujours [tʀavaj].

Albert Cohen note dans son Histoire d'une langue, le français (4e édition, 1973) « L'accent proprement parisien était connu pour exagérer la différence entre un a d'avant et un a d’arrière. [...] Les sondages récents indiquent que la distinction s'effacerait chez beaucoup de personnes, en faveur d'un a moyen ».   Donc la question à poser serait plutôt de savoir pourquoi il y avait une différence de prononciation entre ces deux mots.

Je vous remercie tous deux pour vos commentaires.
Tous vos points ont été très utiles pour moi, qui suis non francophone.
Comme indiqué dans un des commentaires, la question que j'aurais dû poser était la suivante : « la question à poser serait plutôt de savoir pourquoi il y avait une différence de prononciation entre ces deux mots. » Y a-t-il une explication historique à cette différence de prononciation ?

Trouvé cette vidéo How to pronounce AIL - AILLE in French et ça correspond à ce que je constate en France métropolitaine. Peut-être qu'une différence de prononciation aient été l'héritage d’orthographe différentes dues aux étymologies différentes. Faudrait remonter jusqu'en ancien français. Spontanément je ne peux rien dire de plus.

Je vous remercie pour vos réponses fréquentes.
Malheureusement, ces deux types d'a n'ont pas été mentionnés dans la vidéo que vous m'avez donnée.
Je vais me pencher un peu plus sur des livres de phonétique historique. Je vous remercie de tout cœur !

Je n'arrive pas à sentir une différence entre bétail, travail et bataille. À mon avis, si différence il y a eu, elle est en voie d'extinction bien avancée.

Une réponse précieuse. Grand merci.

Usito (dictionnaire québécois) et mon Petit Robert 2022 (papier) indiquent tous les deux travail [tʀavaj] et
bataille [batɑj]. C’est bien de cette manière que ces mots sont prononcés au Québec.

Il y a 50 ans dans l'Est de la France, j'apprenais à l'école que les deux syllabes se prononcent de la même manière. Les formes conjuguées de travailler, itou. Seul bâiller et dérivés étaient traités à part à cause de l'accent circonflexe.

Je vous remercie pour vos précieuses suggestions. Il est possible que les deux prononciations ne soient guère distinguées en France. En revanche, le français québécois semble distinguer les deux prononciation.

Les a de « pâte » et « patte »  sont de moins en moins  prononcés différemment l'un de l'autre de nos jours (pâte [pat] / patte [pat]).
« Patte » contre « pâte » : qui fait encore la différence ?
Dans les mots du type « travail » il existe une telle variété que rien ne permet d'apprendre les prononciations exactes ; il vaut mieux constater que  [a] est souvent utilisé pour les deux a (7 sur 10), avec assez souvent l'option [ɑ:] pour le second a (4 sur 10), et qu'assez rarement il n'existe que cette option pour le second a (3 sur 10).
(voir ci-dessous les mots et leur prononciation telle que tirée du TLFi).

travail [tʀavaj],  bataille [batɑ:j], racaille [ʀakaj], [ʀakɑ:j],  pagaille  [pagaj], canaille [kanɑ:j] ou [-naj], chamaille [ʃamɑ:j], hache-paille [aʃpɑ:j], margaille [maʀgaj], marmaille  [maʀma:j], [-aj], valetaille [valtɑ:j], [-aj].

Pour l'apprenant, il est préférable d'utiliser soit [a] pour les deux a soit [a] pour le premier et [ɑ:] pour le second. Croire qu'il existe une caractéristique fondamentale de la graphie qui fasse qu'un son a plutôt qu'un autre soit plus judicieux n'a pas de sens.
L'explication des  différences ne peut pas être déterminée ; il faudrait tenir compte des différences régionales en moyens de phonation des populations, des influences causées par les contacts entres personnes de régions différentes, puis des mélanges de population, et probablement d'autres facteurs (quelqu'un en trouvera peut-être d'autres) ; il est possible qu'avec des moyens raisonnables, des explications très partielles puissent être obtenues, mais pas plus.

Je vous remercie pour votre commentaire. Je ne suis pas francophone, c'est donc très utile que vous m'ayiez dit quelle prononciation est préférable. Quant aux mots du type « travail », comme vous l'avez montré dans la liste, l'explication de la différence de prononciation est très compliquée. Je me pencherai un peu plus sur la question. Je vous remercie de votre attention.
